# Performance of using cursor PLSQL

Tags: performance, plsql, cursor

I have to get a count using a cursor.
the basic cursor is

```
get *
from table
```

In here there are three types of data I want to get the count of.

```
sysdate < start_date
sysdate > startdate and sysdate < enddate
sysdate > enddate
```

I have 2 ways of doing this.

1. Loop the above cursor and use a if condition to get the counts.
2. Create 3 separate cursors with the conditions and directly get the count

As I have a lot of data what way would be good in perspective of performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3. Don't use a cursor at all.

Use conditional aggregation. That's almost surely faster than any cursor based approach.

```
SELECT count(CASE
               WHEN sysdate < start_date THEN
                 1
             END) count1,
       count(CASE
               WHEN sysdate > startdate
                    AND sysdate < enddate THEN
                 1
             END) count2,
       count(CASE
               WHEN sysdate > enddate THEN
                 1
             END) count3
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: This is a good approach. But I have heard that cursors handle exceptions and it's an advantage we are using throughout this project. Will that be an issue if I use this ?.

Comment: You have "have heard that cursors handle exceptions" well you heard wrong. A cursor is nothing but a SQL statement that allows you to process the rows returned 1 at a time. They cannot handle exceptions. Exceptions can ONLY be handled by the Exception section of a pl/sql block. And you write the code for what it does.